# OpenWRT image for OrangePi

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, openwrt

I need to build the OpenWRT image for OrangePi PC and|or OrangePi Plus board, preferably with working Ethernet and HDMI. I have studied related resources on the internet, like OpenWRT and linux-sunxi websites, but did not find clear instructions.

Comment: You can use OpenWRT, the point is, do you really want to? I used an openWRT image for a lamobo R1, and honestly I hated it, maybe because in addition to the limitations of it, it is a shoddy work by sinovoip (the chinese vendor) for the R1 -and to boot, had some configurations very specific to China. In contrast, I have been using OpenWRT in a TP-Link/Archer C7 v2, and it is so much better than the original firmware. Have a look at Armbian, they are doing a great job supporting Debian in several ARM SBCs. I have been using Armbian as a router/DNS/VPN/VLANs/asterisk and very happy with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for yor comment. I need exactly OpenWRT for the exactly designated hardware (OrangePi) for the purposes of the purpose of some software development and testing, not real production use by me. Installing Debian or Ubuntu is not an isuue at all, there is good description and kernel from @loboris, but I am looking now exactly fo the OpenWRT.

Comment: On the current site, there is a long instruction, but it says that applies to CC, which is old now.  The current supported version for the hardware is marked as 18.06.x, and it says the long instruction to build an SD card image is not necessary after CC.  Current versions should build the whole SD card image for you.  Rejoice!  VTC as "unclear"; you have not pointed to specific instructions you tried to follow.  It might not be 100% your fault that it's not clear what you were asking, two years later :-), but I think that's the situation.